# Windows Azure: Unexpected & unclean virtual-machine shutdown

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Using a large instance of a virtual machine on Windows Azure.  The instance runs Microsoft SQL 2012 with light usage, on Windows Server 2012 + all up to date.  No user is logged in at time of failures.

However, several (between none and three) times a day (appears random), the VM halts and shuts down.  It does not come back online until someone logs back into the Management Portal and starts the VM again.  There is no memory dump created.  So I am guessing the host halts the running VM, rather than some configuration instance within the guest OS causes the halt.  The subscription has billable funds.  Other VMs in the subscription are also affected.

Only event logs generated:

`Kernel-Power` logged:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This
>   error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or
>   lost power unexpectedly.

`Kernel-Boot` logged:

> The last shutdown's success status was false. The last boot's success
>   status was true.

How can this be resolved?  There is no way to initiate a support request within Azure.

Comment: You accepted an answer below but what was the final cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point I would do is install some monitoring software like newrelic or foglight and see if you can see if you are running out memory or a process is pushing the CPU into a spin.

This will give you some visibility of the activity on the box over time and give you some evidence should you need it to open a support request.

Azure now has paid support only 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/plans/

We use developer for exactly this type of situation where you are bit lost to figuring out a situation the cost of $30 dollars compared to running a SQL Server 2012 VM per month makes it worth having. The support under Microsoft are generally very good and they will have more diagnostic information and will be able to give you the heads up if this is because of Azure failure or something else.

Getting diagnostic going though would be first port of call then you can see what is going on and get some evidence together and help you track down the problem.